# SNMP purpose of OBJECT-GROUP, MODULE-COMPLIANCE with regards to OBJECT-TYPES

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

I am implementing my own MIB and also use smilint to check to validate the MIB. I am getting a lot of `node xxx must be contained in at least one conformance group` warnings.

I am having trouble deciphering the purpose of the OBJECT-GROUP and where it fits in the MIB file. Does it provide a mechanism for grouping related managed OBJECT-TYPES located at various OIDs in the same OID subtree? Is it really required since I can design a useful MIB with out it?

I am also struggling to understand the purpose of the MODULE-COMPLIANCE macro relating to the objects. Is this applicable for when extending the MIB I am creating?

A similar question has been asked on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823593/snmp-mib-smiv2-conformance-group-issue) which I sill find unclear since the OBJECT-GROUP is defined under one OID and the referenced OBJECT-TYPEs under a completely different tree.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OBJECT-GROUP macro is, as you state, used to group conceptually related managed OBJECT-TYPES located at various OIDs.  However, they do not have to be from the same subtree. The OBJECT-GROUP macros are not, strictly speaking, required as the fact that it is only a level 4 warning from smilint will attest.

The answer you linked to does mention some of this, but hopefully this is a more useful answer for you.

As to the purpose of these things, I will attempt to explain. These OBJECT-GROUP and MODULE-COMPLIANCE macros are intended for those that will implement the MIB you are creating, rather than for anything to do with the MIB itself. The OBJECT-GROUPs give an idea about the logical relationships of the OIDs and the MODULE-COMPLIANCE statement shows which OIDs are mandatory under what circumstances. i.e from [RFC2580](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2580):

> The compliance statement contained in the (hypothetical) XYZv2-MIB
> might be:
>
> ```
>     xyzMIBCompliance MODULE-COMPLIANCE
>
>     DESCRIPTION
> ```

```
           "The compliance statement for XYZv2 entities which
           implement the XYZv2 MIB."
      MODULE  -- compliance to the containing MIB module
      MANDATORY-GROUPS { xyzSystemGroup,
                         xyzStatsGroup, xyzTrapGroup,
                         xyzSetGroup,
                         xyzBasicNotificationsGroup }
      GROUP   xyzV1Group
      DESCRIPTION
          "The xyzV1 group is mandatory only for those
           XYZv2 entities which also implement XYZv1."
::= { xyzMIBCompliances 1 }
```

> According to this invocation, to claim alignment with the compliance
> statement named

> ```
>    { xyzMIBCompliances 1 }
> ```

> a system must implement the XYZv2-MIB's xyzSystemGroup,
> xyzStatsGroup, xyzTrapGroup, and xyzSetGroup object conformance
> groups, as well as the xyzBasicNotificationsGroup notifications
> group.  Furthermore, if the XYZv2 entity also implements XYZv1, then
> it must also support the XYZv1Group group, if compliance is to be
> claimed.

So, as stated in the other question if you do decide to create OBJECT-GROUP macros, you should probably then follow through and also create the supporting MODULE-COMPLIANCE objects to go with them since you've already gone to the trouble.